# wp-admin change to index.php when acessing dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I moved my wp site to 1&1 hosting after setting it up on my localhost. I change the values in the database, in the admin menu etc etc. Almost all the links are working.

Except the links in the admin sidebar (left).

Just after logging in, the url is sub.mysite.com/wp-admin, 0.5 seconds later it change to sub.mysite.com/index.php

so every links in the admin section are like :

http://sub.mysite.com/index.php/edit.php (for display all posts in this example)

So every links redirect to homepage (/index.php without wp-admin)

Links in the topbar works fine :

http://sub.mysite.com/wp-admin/post-new.php (when trying to create new post from the topbar).

What I am missing ?

Thank you !

Comment: check with your .htaceess file and also need to check that rewrite module is enable or not on host server.

Comment: my .htaccess file is empty ! and the rewrite module is enable

Comment: solved by reinstalling wp directly on the server and reinstall plugins etc.

Answer (score 0):

if .htaccess fil is empty then write below code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

# END WordPress

save it and run it.

i hope its working.

Comment: I pasted this code in my htaccess, it didn't work :/

Comment: please make sure that your re-write module is enable and it's working properly.